# $_post not posting in php and mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, post

I have the the following code however the data only goes into the applicant table and not the applicant_edit table, and apparently I am having this error around the program, I may think it has something to do with the $_post but im not sure, also I have the same exact application running on another computer and it works fine, here is what i did, on this new machine, whiche seems to not be working well, I installed apache, then copied over my entire server folder with all the setting from my other machine, most things seem to be working however when it comes to $_post, thats where errors occur. Please Id love some help and suggestions.

```
<?php
include("config.php"); // put the *FULL* path to the file.

$url = 'index.php';
header('Location: ' . $url);

//header('Location: ' . $url);

$values = $_POST;

foreach ($values as &$value) {
    $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
}

$sq1="INSERT INTO applicant (app_trn,app_file_id, app_fname, app_lname,app_mid_name, app_strt_add_1, app_strt_add_2,app_city, app_parish, app_postal,
 app_hme_cntct, app_cell1_cntct, app_cell2_cntct, app_email, app_gov_agncy, app_gov_agncy_strt,app_gov_agncy_city, app_gov_agncy_parish, app_post,
 app_grade,app_appointment_date,app_salary,app_gov_last_agncy1,app_gov_last_agncy1_street,app_gov_last_agncy1_city,app_gov_last_agncy1_parish,
 app_gov_last_agncy1_contact, app_gov_last_agncy2, app_gov_last_agncy2_street,app_gov_last_agncy2_city,app_gov_last_agncy2_parish,app_gov_last_agncy2_contact,
 app_gov_last_agncy3,app_gov_last_agncy3_street,app_gov_last_agncy3_city,app_gov_last_agncy3_parish,app_gov_last_agncy3_contact)

VALUES
('$values[app_trn]','$values[app_file_id]', '$values[app_fname]','$values[app_lname]', '$values[app_mid_name]','$values[app_strt_add_1]', '$values[app_strt_add_2]', 
'$values[app_city]', '$values[app_parish]', '$values[app_postal]', '$values[app_hme_cntct]', '$values[app_cell1_cntct]', '$values[app_cell2_cntct]',
'$values[app_email]', '$values[app_gov_agncy]', '$values[app_gov_agncy_strt]', '$values[app_gov_agncy_city]', '$values[app_gov_agncy_parish]','$values[app_post]',
'$values[app_grade]','$values[app_appointment_date]','$values[app_salary]','$values[app_gov_last_agncy1]','$values[app_gov_last_agncy1_street]',
'$values[app_gov_last_agncy1_city]','$values[app_gov_last_agncy1_parish]','$values[app_gov_last_agncy1_contact]', '$values[app_gov_last_agncy2]', 
'$values[app_gov_last_agncy2_street]','$values[app_gov_last_agncy2_city]','$values[app_gov_last_agncy2_parish]','$values[app_gov_last_agncy2_contact]',
'$values[app_gov_last_agncy3]','$values[app_gov_last_agncy3_street]','$values[app_gov_last_agncy3_city]','$values[app_gov_last_agncy3_parish]',
'$values[app_gov_last_agncy3_contact]')";

$result = mysql_query($sq1);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_query("INSERT INTO applicant_edit (applicant_edit_id,edit_app_trn)
VALUES ('','$values[app_trn]')");

?>
```

Comment: why your do this redirect "header('Location: ' . $url);" ?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: If the problem was with $_POST it wouldn't go to the first table either. Do a dump of $_POST after your first insertion `print_r($_POST)`.

Comment: What's the question here? What errors are you seeing?

Comment: Ok i get that using pdo would be better but why is it that if works fine on one computer and doesnt on another?

Comment: What are the errors? You've just shown what you've done, not what the result was. "Doesn't work" is not a result that can be diagnosed.

Answer (score 2):

You're redirecting all traffic to index.php before anything happens

```
$url = 'index.php';
header('Location: ' . $url);
```

Remove that and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

1- Remove header redirect code as mentioned by Paul
2- Try to print out one value

```
echo $values[app_trn];
echo "'$values[app_trn]'"; //test same case (double quota and single quota)
```

if it works, then, it will be sql error, try to print

```
echo mysql_error();
```

3- 
I also suggest to use:

```
foreach ($values as &$value) {
    $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
}
```

after this add:

```
foreach ($values as $kc => $vc){
    $$kc = $vc;
 }
```

now all values can be accessed by using key names:

```
VALUES
('$app_trn','$app_file_id', '$valuesapp_fname', ...
```